# ...you want (to)

Tags: ellipses

> a. You can't play, but you want (to).
> b. You can leave whenever you want (to).

In (a), I think the version with "to" at the end is more idiomatic, but in (b), I think the version without "to" is more idiomatic. If my observation is correct, how can I explain the different preferences in what seem to be similar constructions?

Comment: Since (a) uses _don't_ in the first clause, it hasta use _do_ in the second: _I don't wanna play, but you do_. In (b), either form is OK, though final _want to_ is always pronounced _wanna_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks. Right. I've changed (a). In (a), either the former version or the new version, I wouldn't pronounce _want to_ as _wanna_. In (b), I think I wouldn't pronounce it as _wanna_, either. Is it wrong to pronounce it just as in (a)?

Comment: "You can play, and you want to" doesn't sound very idiomatic to me. What is it supposed to mean? When would you say it?

Comment: @StuartF I think I can say it myself, but I've changed it again. Does the new one sound idiomatic to you?

Comment: I don't think there's an explanation. Certain conjunctions prefer "to" after them. So "but" needs "to", while "if" or "whenever" don't.

Comment: @StuartF In what situation? How about "I can work, but I don't really want to." It means "I want/don't want to do X", where X is the thing previously mentioned.

Comment: I think example (a) has more problems than if the marker *to* can be omitted or not. It can't. A more idiomatic and problematic phrase might have been: **If you want [to], we can play** or **We can play if you want**

Comment: @Mari-LouA — *If you want, we can play* and *We can play if you want* are both completely idiomatic to my American English ears.

Comment: @TinfoilHat they are idiomatic for me too, so why is the infinitive marker "to" in "We can play if you want to" optional? Perhaps, 1 a) *You can't play* b) **But I want** ***to*** might have been easier to compare with  the OP's second example  **You can leave whenever you want (to)**

Answer (score 3):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/want) touches upon the matter.

> *We always follow **want** with a complement of some kind*. The complement completes the meaning of the clause. The complement can be a noun or pronoun as an object, or ***a verb in the to-infinitive form***, or an object plus a verb in the to-infinitive form:
> A: Is Elsa going to France with you?
> B: No. She doesn’t want to. (She doesn’t want to go [to France].)
> Not: <del>She doesn’t want.</del>

So even if you omit the verb ***go*** from the complement to avoid repetition, *to* needs to stay there for the sentence to be complete. Note also that ***want*** cannot be followed by *that* clauses, only by infinitives or by object+to infinitive.

Things are different though when ***want*** is preceded by *wh- words*:

> We can use wh-words such as ***what, when, whenever, wherever, whoever*** before ***want***. In such cases, *it is often ***not necessary*** to use the infinitive ***to*** after want*:
>
> - You don’t have to stay for the whole lecture. You can leave whenever you want. (or … whenever you want to.)

There is also mention about the use of the infinitive after *want* in combination with *if*:

> In statements with *if*, it is often not necessary to use the infinitive ***to*** after *want*:
>
> - She can park her car at our house, ***if she wants***.
>
> However, we use the infinitive ***to*** after want in *negative* clauses with *if*:
>
> - He doesn’t have to stay the night *if he doesn’t want **to***.

Comment: I think it would be useful to include in your answer this part from your reference page: "In statements with *if*, it is often not necessary to use the infinitive to after *want*: *She can park her car at our house, if she wants*. However, we use the infinitive *to* after *want* in negative clauses with *if*: *He doesn’t have to stay the night if he doesn’t want to.*"

Comment: @TinfoilHat You are right. Done.

Answer (score 1):

The examples differ markedly.

> **a. You can't play, but you want (to).**

This comprises two main clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction (but). In such combinations, following "want", a "to infinitive" as an object is required, this "to infinitive" acts as an NP, but is often reduced to "to" (with a parallel implied infinitive (play))

Compare: "You can't play but you want a prize"

> **b. You can leave whenever you want (to).**

(a) This comprises a main clause joined by a subordinating conjunction (whenever) to an adverbial clause. As the second clause is adverbial, the "to infinitive" is optional and is optionally indicated by "to".

(b) In the alternative, "whenever you want" can be used intransitively to mean "whenever that (= leaving/to leave) is your wish".

The adverbial clause can be further reduced to simply "whenever."

Comment: *As the second clause is adverbial, the "to infinitive" is optional and is optionally indicated by "to".* <-- I don't think that this is correct. For example: "She entered the contest because she wanted to." Even though it's in an adverbial clause, "to" is not optional.